# Install PDO_OCI on Zend Server VirtualBox Appliance

Tags: php, oracle, joomla, pdo, zend-server

I have installed the VM using the instructions [here](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/virtualbox) and have successfully setup and Oracle DB and a Joomla! test site.

I have connected to the oracle db with PHP using oci_connect. Now I'm trying to do the same using the Joomla! site but have run into a problem where PDO cannot find driver.

I believe I need to install the pdo_oci driver but have no idea how to do it or even where to get it from. I'm also surprised it is not preinstalled in the VM.

Can anyone point me in the direction of a 'How to' for installing the driver please?

Thanks!